# Hibernate JPA connections

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an Item entity and an Order entity.Order has an ManyToOne relation with some items(Many orders to one item).Now in the order entity I have to point some characteristic of that item.I need the model of the item for example.

**How can I do that?**
One weapon to many Orders ?

Comment: Each item should point to its `ItemCharacteristic`, for example.

Comment: Another many to one worked for me ...Many orders to one weapon